# How to Use Sessions to walk user through Sign Up?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, session, model-view-controller

On the home page:

**sessions/_goal.html.erb**

```
<%= simple_form_for(:session, url: new_goal_path) do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field :name %>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
  # ERROR MESSAGE:
    Routing Error
    No route matches [POST] "/goals/new"
```

Once the user submit's that he should be redirected to:

**sessions/_habit.html.erb**

```
<%= simple_form_for(:session, url: new_habit_path) do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field :name %>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

Once the user submit's that he should be redirected to:

```
<%= link_to "Sign Up via Facebook", "/auth/facebook" %> or
<%= link_to "Sign Up via Email", signup_path %>
```

The information they put in those two partials should then be stored so that when they are signed in they will see it as part of their profile.

**sessions_controller.rb**

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController

  def new
  end

  def goal
  end 

  def facebook
    user = User.from_omniauth(env["omniauth.auth"])
    session[:user_id] = user.id
    redirect_to root_url
  end

  def create
    user = User.find_by(email: params[:session][:email].downcase)
    if user && user.authenticate(params[:session][:password])
      if user.activated?
        log_in user
        params[:session][:remember_me] == '1' ? remember(user) : forget(user)
        redirect_to root_url
      else
        message  = "Account not activated. "
        message += "Check your email for the activation link."
        flash[:warning] = message
        redirect_to root_url
      end
    else
      flash.now[:danger] = 'Invalid email/password combination'
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def destroy
    log_out if logged_in?
    redirect_to root_url
  end
end
```

**routes**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  put '/mark_completed/:id', to: 'habits#mark_completed', as: 'mark_completed'

  put '/mark_accomplished/:id', to: 'goals#mark_accomplished', as: 'mark_accomplished'

  get 'notes/index'

  get 'notes/new'

  get 'notifications/index'

  get 'auth/:provider/callback', to: 'sessions#facebook'
  get 'auth/failure', to: redirect('/')
  get 'signout', to: 'sessions#destroy', as: 'signout'

  get 'password_resets/new'

  get 'password_resets/edit'

  get "/users/:user_id/goals", to: "goals#user_goals", as: "user_goals"

  shallow do
    resources :habits do
      resources :comments
      resources :notes
      resources :notifications
    end
    resources :valuations do
      resources :comments
      resources :notes
      resources :notifications
    end
    resources :goals do
      resources :comments
      resources :notes
      resources :notifications
    end
    resources :stats do
      resources :comments
      resources :notes
      resources :notifications
    end
  end

  resources :notes

  resources :habits do
    collection { post :sort }
    resources :notes
    resources :notifications
    resources :comments do
      resources :likes
    end
    resources :likes
    member do
      post :like
      post :notifications
    end
    resources :levels do
      # we'll use this route to increment and decrement the missed days
      resources :days_missed, only: [:create, :destroy]
    end
  end

  resources :goals do
    resources :notes
    resources :comments
    member do
      post :like
    end
  end

  resources :valuations do
    resources :notes
    resources :comments
    resources :notifications
    member do
      post :like
      post :notifications
    end
  end

  resources :stats do
    resources :notes
    resources :comments
    resources :notifications
    member do
      post :like
    end
  end

  resources :results

  resources :users

  resources :account_activations, only: [:edit]

  resources :activities do
    resources :valuations
    resources :habits
    resources :stats
    resources :goals
  end

  resources :notifications do
    resources :valuations
    resources :habits
    resources :stats
    resources :goals
    resources :comments
  end

  resources :comments do
    resources :comments
    resources :notifications
    member do
      post :like
    end
  end

  resources :password_resets,     only: [:new, :create, :edit, :update]

  resources :relationships,       only: [:create, :destroy]

  get 'tags/:tag', to: 'pages#home', as: :tag

  resources :users do
    member do
      get :following, :followers
    end
  end

  get    'about'   => 'pages#about'
  get    'signup'  => 'users#new'
  get    'login'   => 'sessions#new'
  post   'login'   => 'sessions#create'
  delete 'logout'  => 'sessions#destroy'

  root 'pages#home'
```

I have no idea what I'm doing here. Any help would greatly be appreciated :]

Comment: Well, to help us help you – please describe at least *some* idea what you are doing here :) What's your current specific issue/question related to your task?

Comment: Since this is a routing issue the specific routes in question need to be added to the post

Comment: Okay I guess I could have asked this initially based on the very first section. Why are you trying to post to `new_goal_path`? New records are generally get requests as defined by resources. You could resolve this by using a redirect_to in the controller action that you actually want to POST to. Also why are all your forms for a session?

Comment: I am not sure I understand your workflow enough to actually post an answer. What is the purpose of `_goal.html.erb`? using the symbol `:session` will simply create a scope in params for the form submission e.g. `params[:session]` but I don't understand why you are trying to send this to `goals#new`. Explain the workflow concept in greater detail as the error is now fairly obvious but the solution is not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That will take some work.

First, fix your routes (post them here as you was rightfully asked).

Next, change your partials into action templates (remove underscore `_` from their names).

Then in your controller actions use `params[...]` to retrieve data (e.g. `params[:session][:name]` for the first step) and save them in `session` (`session[:name] = params[:session][:name]`).

At the end of action call `redirect_to :another_action` (change :another_action to the concrete action you want next – for example in `goal` method that would be `redirect_to :habit_url` – and you should add that `habit` method to your controller).

Then, in your facebook-related methods you will have `session[:name]` and other stuff available, so you just fetch it from there and push into database (`user.update(name: session[:name])`).

**Reading material**:

**[Action Controller Overview](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html)** – you need to attentively read this first of all

[Active Record Basics](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_basics.html) – how to save user details to database

[Rails Routing from the Outside In](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html) – just look through that, paying attention to places which are relevant to your current setup

Comment: Thanks! Okay so I removed the underscore and made the top line `<%= simple_form_for(:session) do |f| %>`. I then added this to the sessions_controller: `def goal
    if params[:session][:name]
    session[:name] = params[:session][:name]
    redirect_to :habit_url
  end `. Is this right so far?

Comment: I'm going to continue the conversation over here to hopefully clarify the situation: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31906887/how-to-store-nil-users-goal-in-a-session Thanks for your help in getting me this far!