# How to store nil user's goal in a session?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, session, model-view-controller

How to save a user's goal in his session? Then once he signed up, save that goal and delete it from the session?

On the home page it looks like this:

[image]

**goals/_form.html.erb**

```
<%= simple_form_for(@goal) do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field :name %>
  <%= f.text_field :deadline %>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

Upon clicking submit, the `nil` user's goal should be added to his session and then he should be redirected to the signup page whereupon signing up his goal should be added to his newly created account.

**goals_controller**

```
  def create
    @goal = params[:user] ? current_user.goals.build(goal_params) : Goal.new(goal_params)
    if params[:session][:name][:deadline] 
      session[:name][:deadline] = params[:session][:name][:deadline] 
      redirect_to signup_url 
    elsif 
      @goal.save
      track_activity @goal
      redirect_to @goal, notice: 'Goal was successfully created'
    else
      flash.now[:danger] = 'Required Field: "Enter Goal"'
      render 'new'
    end
  end
```

Right now if I click submit as a `nil` user I get:

```
NoMethodError in GoalsController#create
undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
for line: if params[:session][:name][:deadline]
```

Then once he signed up the goal stored in his session should be added to his account. If this last condition is too complex I can make it a separate question.

Comment: What are you using to for logins? Devise?

Comment: What line is the nil error on for the create action? also what is the condition after that elsif?

Comment: wouldn't the param structure for that simple_form_for be params[:goal][:name] and params[:goal][:deadline]? Where is the top level :session coming from? or are you trying to see if that session value exists?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Goals Controller**

```
  def create
    unless params[:user].present?
        # If there is no user, store the goal values to the session
        session[:goal_name] = goal_params[:name]
        session[:goal_deadline] = goal_params[:deadline]
        redirect_to signup_url
    else
        @goal = current_user.goals.build(goal_params)
        if @goal.save
            track_activity @goal
            redirect_to @goal, notice: 'Goal was successfully created'
        else
            flash.now[:danger] = 'Required Field: "Enter Goal"'
            render 'new'
        end
    end
```

**User Controller**

```
def create
    # create user logic
    if @user.save
        # Grab the session variable at the same time deleting it
        gName = session.delete(:goal_name)
        gDeadline = session.delete(:goal_deadline)

        # You can make this more complex for error handling
        @user.goals.create(name: gName, deadline: gDeadline)
        redirect_to success_creation_path
    else
      ...
    end
end
```

Comment: Yw. instead of building it and then saving it you can just create it. i'll change the variable names so its not as confusing

Comment: Thanks again. very nice :]

Comment: Hey @blnc, I added an additional step to the sign up process by requiring a user to also create a habit, but I ran into a problem if you're willing to help me there too :] http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31908491/how-to-store-data-in-session-from-multiple-models