# How to break up an array into strings MVC?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby, session, model-view-controller

If a `current_user` submits a habit, the days he `:committed` to doing it work like this:

> 1. **db** `t.text "committed", default: ["sun", "mon", "tue", "wed", "thu", "fri", "sat"], array: true`
> 2. **habits/_form** `<%= f.collection_check_boxes :committed, Date::ABBR_DAYNAMES, :downcase, :to_s %>` (user chooses days)
> 3. **habits_controller** `habit_params :committed => []`
> 4. **habits/index** `<% habit.committed.map { |d| d.titleize[0,3] }.each do |title| %> <%= title %> <% end %>`

If a `nil` user submits a habit (he is encouraged to create one before signing up), the days he `:committed` to doing it work like this:

> 1. **db** `t.text "committed", default: ["sun", "mon", "tue", "wed", "thu", "fri", "sat"], array: true`
> 2. **habits/_form** `<%= f.collection_check_boxes :committed, Date::ABBR_DAYNAMES, :downcase, :to_s %>` (user chooses days)
> 3. ***habits_controller** `session[:habit_committed] = [params["habit"]["committed"]]`
> 4. ***users_controller** `committed = session.delete(:habit_committed)` `@user.habits.create(committed:
>      committed)`
> 5. **habits/index** `<% habit.committed.map { |d| d.titleize[0,3] }.each do |title| %> <%= title %> <% end %>`

[image]

When both habits were first submitted the terminal looks something like this:

```
Started POST "/habits" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-08-11 13:15:40 -0400
Processing by HabitsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"EDxn180pxfaqNCBNtzxJd3Y0XHO5m9eURhj9WOf25Re64ed0f99HlIXIgHfNpyJIi1KD92SQ/QggcTCf7pZPHw==", "habit"=>{"committed"=>["sun", "mon", "tue", "wed", "thu", "fri", "sat", ""], "date_started(2i)"=>"8", "date_started(3i)"=>"11", "date_started(1i)"=>"2015", "trigger"=>"test", "action"=>"test", "target"=>"test", "reward"=>"test"}, "button"=>""}
Redirected to http://0.0.0.0:3000/valuation_signup
Completed 302 Found in 11ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

But where they differ is when the user finishes signing up I see the terminal conclude such things as: `["committed", "{{NULL}}"]` or `["committed", "{NULL}"]` or `["committed", "{}"]`.

I tried a variety of things such as `.join`, `.split`, `.inspect`, `.map`, `.map(&:inspect).join(', ')`, `.map {|str| "\"#{str}\""}.join(',')` but I'm guessing I didn't use the right concoction or format.

**Sorry** if this question's layout looks like a `ransom` note.

### 1st ATTEMPT

> 1. Changed **db** to `t.text "committed", default: "---\n- sun\n- mon\n- tue\n- wed\n- thu\n- fri\n- sat\n"`
> 2. **habits.rb** `serialize :committed, Array`
> 3. **habits/_form** `<%= f.collection_check_boxes :committed, Date::ABBR_DAYNAMES, :downcase, :to_s %>` (user chooses days)
> 4. **habits_controller** `session[:habit_committed] = [params["habit"]["committed => []"]]`
> 5. ***users_controller** `committed = session.delete(:habit_committed)` `@user.habits.create(committed:
>      committed)`
> 6. **habits/index** `<% habit.committed.map { |d| d.titleize[0,3] }.each do |title| %> <%= title %> <% end %>`

This produced: `["committed", "---\n- \n"]`

Comment: why do you have the ", array: true" in your DB column migration? Look at the docs: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html #Saving arrays, hashes, and other non-mappable objects in text columns

Comment: I know we can serialize in the model. I don't know why that is better than the db though. I'll give your suggestions in chat a second try and then update this question @blnc

Comment: Updated question for you @blnc.

Comment: so this comment doesn't go nuts, I'm going to start an answer and the modify it as we go

Comment: haha okay @blnc. Thank you! :]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are setting your session variable for *committed* you are setting it to an empty array and then are getting an empty array as the value.

In your logs the value for *params["habits"]["committed"]* is already an array so no need to re-parse it or nest it inside other brackets

So give this a try:

> **habits_controller.rb** session[:habit_committed] = params["habit"]["committed"].reject(&:empty?)

Comment: Final question relating to sign up if you want to give this a stab: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31995824/how-to-skip-a-session-create :]