# How to skip a session create?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, session

When a `nil` user clicks "sign up" he is encouraged to submit a goal, habit, and value before being logged in.

But he may skip one of those forms by clicking:

[image]

The problem is if he skips a form right now then an error message pops up:

```
TypeError in UsersController#create
no implicit conversion of nil into String
```

In this example I skipped the habit form so it is being raised on `@user.habits.create(`

**users_controller**

```
  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)
    if @user.save
      # Goals
      name = session.delete(:goal_name)
      deadline = session.delete(:goal_deadline)
      # Values
      vname = session.delete(:valuation_name)
      vimage = session.delete(:valuation_image)
      # Habits
      date_started = session.delete(:habit_date_started)
      committed = session.delete(:habit_committed)
      trigger = session.delete(:habit_trigger)
      action = session.delete(:habit_action)
      target = session.delete(:habit_target)
      reward = session.delete(:habit_reward)
      missed_days = session.delete(:habit_missed_days)
      # Create
      @user.habits.create(date_started: Date.parse(date_started), committed: committed, trigger: trigger, action: action, target: target, reward: reward, missed_days: missed_days).create_with_current_level
      @user.goals.create(name: name, deadline: deadline)
      @user.valuations.create(name: vname, image: vimage)
      @user.send_activation_email
      redirect_to root_url
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end
```

How can we allow the user to skip? I've been trying to include various `if/else` statements, but I'm having a hard time setting the right method to trigger the conditional.

Comment: on what line does the error happen?

Comment: @blnc it happens on whatever form I skipped, so in this example I skipped the habit form so it is being raised on @user.habits.create(

Comment: It should be telling you in which particular line the error is occurring. Likely the result of trying to assign a "Nil" value to an object expecting a "String" value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am going to assume that if they submit the form all the values get populated. That said:

**users_controller**

```
  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)
    make_habit = false
    make_goal = false
    make_valuation = false

    if @user.save
      # Goals
      name = session.delete(:goal_name)
      deadline = session.delete(:goal_deadline)
      make_goal = true  if !name.blank? && !deadline.blank?

      # Values
      vname = session.delete(:valuation_name)
      vimage = session.delete(:valuation_image)
      make_valuation = true  if !vname.blank? && !vimage.blank?

      # Habits
      date_started = session.delete(:habit_date_started)
      committed = session.delete(:habit_committed)
      trigger = session.delete(:habit_trigger)
      action = session.delete(:habit_action)
      target = session.delete(:habit_target)
      reward = session.delete(:habit_reward)
      missed_days = session.delete(:habit_missed_days)
      make_habit = true  if !date_started.blank? && !committed.blank? #(... continue for whatever else you want to make sure is there)

      # Create
      @user.habits.create(date_started: Date.parse(date_started), committed: committed, trigger: trigger, action: action, target: target, reward: reward, missed_days: missed_days).create_with_current_level  if make_habit
      @user.goals.create(name: name, deadline: deadline)  if make_goal
      @user.valuations.create(name: vname, image: vimage)  if make_valuation
      @user.send_activation_email
      redirect_to root_url
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end
```

Comment: It keeps timing out. I'll keep working with it `Net::ReadTimeout (Net::ReadTimeout):
  app/models/user.rb:125:in 'send_activation_email'
  app/controllers/users_controller.rb:58:in 'create'`

Comment: that has to do with your mail config. it's trying to contact a server and not getting a response. comment out the @user.send_activation_email and see if it works

Comment: It redirected back to the `root_url` when I commented out the activation email so I guess that part of it worked, but this creates another problem that previously didn't exist. Now when I go back to the original code in the question it still times out so now I'm really confused. Maybe it's just a coincidence that now it times out due to some unrelated reason.

Comment: the timeout seems unrelated to this action. hard to tell what it is doings without seeing the server logs, check them to see where it is hanging

Comment: Yea it might just have to do with my internet being slow. Hopefully I can solve this on my own. Thanks so much for your help blnc :]